Unable to import selenium.webdriver.common.by
While trying to run selenium commands in Python, I am not able to import selenium.webdriver.common.by. However, the library 'selenium' is finely imported. I am running the program in VS Code.
Script:-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://**.com")
search_id = "123"
search_elem = driver.find_element(By.ID, search_id)
#search_elem.send_keys("**email.com")

breakpoint()

Error:-
PS C:\Users\Desktop\python selenium> python test.py                                                                    

DevTools listening on ws://***/devtools/browser/44ebdc50-e0c6-43e6-a329-85c2e96b0892
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\python selenium\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    search_elem = driver.find_element(By.ID, search_id)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 748, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 354, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="i0116"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=128.0.6613.138); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception



There's nothing wrong with the import. Look at the stack trace. The issue is here: driver.find_element(By.ID, search_id) The problem is that the ID you're looking for cannot be found / doesn't exist. Is your IDE using a different Python environment to the one where you executed the script?

Hello, do you have multiple python environments? Is webdriver installed and added to the system environment variables? This could be the reason why the element is not in the correct position. You can go to the command palette by Ctrl+Shift+P and type select interpreter to select the interpreter with selenium installed.
